# Free lunch Autoencoder? Data dimensionality reduction

Tags: neural-networks, bias, autoencoders, weights

I came across Autoencoders, and saw one example were no activation is used - it's simply a linear transform to lower dimension and then back up
$$ B(Ax+a)+b=x$$ with $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times d}$

But wouldn't the exact solution be $a=\vec{0}, \ b=\vec{0}$ with $B$ the [left inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse) of $A$ (for any $A$ that has a left inverse)? Or if $A$ satisfies $A^TA=I_d$ then just make $B=A^T$?

Seems like any of these solutions would be a perfect way to "autoencode" $x$ without loss of information. So $Ax$ would be a lower dimensional representation of the data, and at any time it can be brought back to $\mathbb{R}^d$ by left multiplying by $B$. Sounds like free lunch? Or is this a useless transformation?

I'm asking this because in the tutorial I'm doing they're using TensorFlow to solve for $A$ and $B$ by gradient descent, but why not just use my proposed solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left inverse of A has dimensions $d \times m$, but exists only when $m \geq d$, so this would be dimensionality expansion, not reduction.

If $d > m$, then $A$ and $B$ have rank at most $m$, which means their product has rank at most $m$ and cannot possibly be the identity matrix.

Comment: Hmm so no free lunch for me :(